# adding a new image after a click

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

i am trying to add a new image when i click the z pass button
my this part of the code is not working

http://jsfiddle.net/UjJEJ/24/

```
$(".ctaSpecialOne").click(function(){                    
                         alert("clicked");  

$(this).parent().unbind("mouseenter").children("img").attr("src", "http://www.onlinegrocerystore.co.uk/images/goodfood.jpg");                


                 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to traverse to the sibling `a` since that's where your image is

```
$(this).parent().unbind("mouseenter").siblings('a').children("img").attr("src", "http://www.onlinegrocerystore.co.uk/images/goodfood.jpg");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WAvVw/

**EDIT**

You need to traverse to get the element which you bound hover to

```
$(this)
   .closest('.specialHoverOne') // get element you bound hover to
   .unbind("mouseenter") // unbind event
   .end() // start over at this
   .parent()  // get parent
   .siblings('a') //find a sibling
   .children("img") // get children img
   .attr("src", "http://www.onlinegrocerystore.co.uk/images/goodfood.jpg"); // change src
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mwPeb/

I'm sure there's a better way to traverse but I'm short on time right now

Comment: thanks for your reply but the zpass button should not appear once the image is added...how to achieve it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WAvVw/1/ by background color also not working  $(this).css("background-color","red");

Comment: instead of adding the new image is it possible to change the opacity of same image so that i can increase browser speed